# PyInstaller: Alternative folder location for dependencies

Tags: python, python-3.4, pyinstaller

I am writing an App with Kivy and followed this [Tutorial](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html).
Everything runs fine, but I don't like the folder structure. I tried the one-folder and one-file approach, but [here](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) (in Features) it lists a third option of customizing it. I would like my app to be packaged in a way that all of its files and folder structure remains as it was. Additionally I want the generated exe to be on the root of my app and all the dependencies/libraries to either be in the lib folder of my app, or packaged with the exe. I have read [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html) about it, but couldn't find anything. Also a search on Google didn't give me much.

This is how I want want it to look like:

```
- folder
  - somecode.py
  - othercode.py
- lib
  - dependency1
  - dependency2
  - ...
- main.py
- myapp.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I talked to the people on the PyInstaller IRC chat and they told me that it is not possible as of yet. The website doesn't state (what I thought) that there are 3 options (one folder, one file or custom), but that there are two options (one folder, one file) and that you can customize which of those two you want to use. This is why I will try out cx_freeze instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's similar task - to pack all the sources in a separate folder and keep them as they are.
However it was solved with py2exe, solution is based on configuring setuptools. I hope it will be useful.

[Python - create an EXE that runs code as written, not as it was when compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906523/python-create-an-exe-that-runs-code-as-written-not-as-it-was-when-compiled/36112722#36112722)

Comment: Thanks, that might do what I want, I'll try it out.