# How to remove clutter from PyInstaller one-folder build?

Tags: python, build, pygame, pyinstaller

Alright, so I managed to use PyInstaller to build a homework assignment I made with Pygame. Cool. The executable works fine and everything.

Problem is, alongside the executable, there is so much clutter. So many files, like pyds and dlls accompany the exe in the same directory, making it look so ugly.

Now, I know that these files are important; the modules I used, such as Pygame, need them to work. Still, how do I make PyInstaller build my game, so that it puts the clutter into its own folder? I could just manually make a folder and move the files in there, but it stops the exe from working.

If this info would help any, I used Python 3.4.3 and am on Windows.

Comment: I ran into the same issue some time ago and "solved" it by creating a shortcut of the `.exe` one level higher.

Comment: @Repiklis How do you do that, so the end user won't have to do anything fancy? When I make a shortcut, it only works for the particular path on my computer; it won't work if I send the program to someone else, since they're on a different computer.

Comment: The issue is the program folders declared in the shortcut. I am not at a windows pc at the moment and my memory is a bit foggy. If I remember correctly, you have to go into the shortcut properties and remove the "starts in" folder. I'll give it a try tomorrow. If you beat me to it, let me know.

Comment: Have you considered packaging in the one-file mode instead of one-dir?
This would keep all of the 'ugly' file dependencies relatively out of sight (living in a temp directory during the execution instead).
Does the teacher/professor want or need to look directly at the source while actively running the exe?

Comment: I have. Also, the assignment was from a book, so I don't really have a teacher looking to get something turned in. The problem with one-file mode is how it keeps glitching out. That, and it looks nicer to me to have some files and folders alongside the exe, so long as it's not too much (the pyinstaller clutter is WAY too much).

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this is an [open request for `pyinstaller`](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1048), but hasn't happened in the past two years.

My workaround for this one was to create a shortcut one folder higher than the `.exe` folder with all the files.

The difficult part here is to set up the shortcut to work in all PCs. [I did two things in the shortcut properties](https://superuser.com/questions/644407/using-relative-paths-for-windows-shortcuts).

1. Delete the "Starts in:" path
2. Set as the "Target": `"%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" /c start "" "%CD%\YourFolder\YourEXE.exe"`

The second one calls a command line and launches your exe with a relative path. I have only tested it with windows 7. The downside is that this becomes a shortcut to the command line and you get a console window.

A different option is to create a batch file in the one folder higher than the `.exe` and call it. This shows only briefly the console window, but won't allow you to set your own icon. A sample code that launches your code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set CDir=%~dp0
set EXEF=%CDir%MyEXEFolder\
cd %EXEF%
start "MyCode" "MyCode.exe"
exit
```

Just open a notepad, add the code and save it as a `.bat` file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36112722/3837382) also describes a workaround with `py2exe`, but a similar approach can be used in `pyinstaller`. However, I find this quite "ugly" and I am not sure if it's that easy to collect all dependencies in one folder.

There is also [Relative](http://www.csparks.com/Relative/), but I didn't want to use another program.

Comment: About step 2, what is the "%CD" part supposed to be?

Comment: [%CD% is the current working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419868/what-is-the-current-directory-in-a-batch-file). It is the folder that contains the shortcut if you double click it.

Comment: Tried it, and it works. But, isn't there another way that doesn't bring up the command window?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no option that I have tried that doesn't show the console even briefly. Maybe Relative will do what you want. I expanded the answer with all the approaches I know of.

Comment: What is the CDir in the batch file example you gave?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034076/what-does-dp0-mean-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Nothing there explains what CDir is :/

Comment: It is just a variable name. You can use whatever you want. I didn't get that you were asking that. The link explains %~dp0, which assigns a value to the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Not trying to dig up this old question, but this was at the top of my Google search so it may be for others as well.

If you intend to distribute the program in some kind of folder, you can always just mark everything unnecessary as hidden in Windows, and it will remain hidden even if you compress or extract it.

For a program that I designed to be very user friendly, I just selected each file and folder that was not necessary to the user and hid them. If the user has show hidden files on (rarely default), they aren't likely to be intimidated by the mess of files that pyinstaller creates.