# Adding Python EntryPoints at runtime

Tags: python, python-decorators, entry-point

Starting by hypothesys that I have already defined and installed a package with and entrypoint that looks like:

```
setup(...
    entry_points={
        'group.subgrp': []
    }
...)
```

Then during runtime I would love to define some functions and attach them as entrypoints. The pseudo-code could looks like:

```
@Entrypoint.attach(group='group.subgrp', name='dummy_name')
def my_dummy_function():
    ....
```

Is that doable?

EDIT: After write the question, I have came to conclusion that this makes no sense, since the callable defined on entrypoints are 'accessible'  even if the package isn't being "ran". Anyway I will leave the question here, just to hear from community.

Comment: Very much related https://stackoverflow.com/q/40514205/11715259, almost a duplicate? Yet the here present question is much more focused, better quality, IMHO, and including the thought that this would be an anti-pattern.