# Running entry point console_script in python development environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

What is the process for running console scripts that use entry points as a python package developer?

I have a python project that has a `setup.py` with.  In it, I have a

```
 entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myscript=mypackage.myscript.__main__:main',
        ]
    },
```

If I do `python setup.py develop`, I *do* end up with the wrapper scripts in `virtualenv/bin`, but when I run them I get an error:

> ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'myscript') not found

(the above *does* work if I do `pip install .`)

Now, from the top of the project, I can copy the wrapper script and manually do:

```
$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr 25 2019, 21:02:35) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
>>> load_entry_point('mypackage', 'console_scripts', 'myscript')
<function main at 0x7f7b971bcea0>
>>>
```

So, what I take from this is that `virtualenv/bin/myscript` is looking in the `virtualenv` for the package and when I run it manually from the top of my dev environment, it looks for packages in my current directory.

I don't want to run it out of my `virtualenv` though.  I don't want to have to do `pip install .` every time I want to try a modification to my script.

What is the expected workflow here?  To manually run `python -m mypackage.myscript`?  I'd rather run it just like users will.  Copy the virtualenv/bin scripts?  Then they could become out of date...

I am unable to find this aspect of the development workflow in the setuptools docs.

update:

I did find this in my virtualenv after `setup.py develop`:

```
$ more virtualenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mypackage.egg-link
/home/me/src/mypackage.git
.
```

Comment: Normally it should work.  Instead of `./setup.py develop` try `pip install -e .` and see if that works any better.

Comment: Argh -- yes, that works.  And then I `pip uninstall mypackage` and rerun `setup.py develop` and it still works as well.  I'll see if I can reproduce.

Comment: AllI can guess was somehow my `mypackage.egg-info/entry_points.txt` was out of date.  But can't reproduce it.

Comment: The console script entry point is just a shim (written out by then installer) which imports your Python function and runs it. It has a shebang that is associated with the Python executable which was used to install the distribution, so this will be the virtualenv's python if you installed package within the virtualenv.  **Ergo, you do not have to reinstall console_scripts every time you modify the library code.**  You only have to reinstall if adding/removing entry points. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As suggested by @Iguananaut, I ran `pip install -e .` instead.

It now works.

So I then did a `pip uninstall mypackage` and did a `python setup.py develop` again to reproduce.  It didn't reproduce.

I now understand that `load_entry_point` literally reads the `entry_points.txt` from the `mypackage.egg-info`.  My only guess is that somehow that file was bad... and not getting fixed by running `python setup.py develop`.

So -- the answer to my query is:

For running console scripts in a dev environment, use `pip install -e .` and run the scripts out of the `virtualenv/bin/`.  It's designed to work that way, and if it doesn't -- something else is wrong.

Comment: Note that the `load_entry_point` thing is only used for editable installs.  A normal install will not use this "hack", it will generate a proper script with library import.

Comment: In my case doing a `pip install -e .` doesn't work still and gives me and gives me a `sys.exit(load_entry_point('fitbapp', 'console_scripts', 'manage-server')())` error. Can somebody help?