# Install and execute python3 inside one same independent folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a small program written with Python3 that I'd like to install on friends computers. The main issue is that not every computer has a Python3 installed on it (mostly Python2-). Do I have to install it on each computer I want my program to run?

I thought it would be possible to install Python3 inside a separate directory, as shown below.

[image]

Then, I would be able to use a shebang to run the right version of Python installed inside `myProgram` folder.

```
#!C:\myProgram\python3 python

# Test
a = input('Entrer un nom:')
print(a)
```

When I double-click on `myProgram.py` file, a window opens and closes immediatly...

Is this a bad idea or not? Is there a way to achieve that differetnly if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an executable from the python script rather than installing all of python 3 on their machine. There's a few ways you can do it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136837/process-to-convert-simple-python-script-into-windows-executable).
I'd have a look at [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

Comment: Yes I think that's the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add Python 3 to your friends machine to execute your program. 
What'is the utility to run such a small program on their computers?

Answer (score 0):

The way you propose won't work.

1. Windows does not know about shebangs.
2. Even if it did, this one would only work if a user installed the program to C:\myProgram (which is not a really appropriate place, and the user might not have the rights to install it there).

There are ways to make a python program portable w/o having the need to have a Python runtime installed. Alas, I currently don't know their name.

Or, if that is feasible, install Python 3 on their machines, but I don't know if that might break any programs wanting to use Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

There're different tools which can pack you program to single .exe file or make an installer. Here's my solution from 2016 year - [Python - create an EXE that runs code as written, not as it was when compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906523/python-create-an-exe-that-runs-code-as-written-not-as-it-was-when-compiled/36112722#36112722)

Now it will be little easier :)