# ImportError on python exe file

Tags: python

Using py2exe I create an exe version of my script with instructions I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601047/import-a-python-module-without-the-py-extension). The script compiles well and generates a dist and build folder each but when I run the program on the command line it gives this error. N.B the script works fine on my IDE environment, however I intend give a colleague the exe version.How can I fix this error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tester2.py", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named mechanize
```

here is the setup.py file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(

    console = ['tester2.py'],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare your dependencies.
This is my setup

```
setup(
    executables=executables,
    options=options,
    name='bla',
    version='0.3',
    packages=[...],
    url='',
    license='',
    author='',
    author_email='',
    description='', requires=['pandas', 'unidecode', 'click',
                              'xlsxwriter'] // you would have to add mechanize here
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added files to the build?

Pls have a look at `include` option in `setup.py`: [exe built with cx_Freeze, PyQt5, Python3 can't import ExtensionLoader_PyQt5_QtWidgets.py and run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31680439/exe-built-with-cx-freeze-pyqt5-python3-cant-import-extensionloader-pyqt5-qtwi?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Also here's my solution to similar problem, how to add files to build and run them later: [Python - create an EXE that runs code as written, not as it was when compiled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906523/python-create-an-exe-that-runs-code-as-written-not-as-it-was-when-compiled/36112722#36112722)